# Have custom data with the Facebook Share dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

With Facebook Open Graph v2.0 the Feed Dialog became deprecated. I always used the feed dialog when dynamic meta data was needed to be shared.

For example, with a function like: "Share your score on Facebook" - before v2.0 this could be used:

```
var myScore = 20;

FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'My score was: ' + myScore + ' in AppName' ,
    link: 'https://appname.com',
}, function(response){});
```

Facebook says use the Share dialog instead as of v2.0.

> On web, developers are encouraged to use the more modern Share Dialog, which can perform all of the same functions as these older dialogs, but can additionally publish custom Open Graph stories without requiring Facebook Login.

But does it really have the same functionality? It seems I cannot add custom parameters, this makes it harder to share dynamic meta data than before.

The share dialogs documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

So I cannot add parameters to make the share dialog more dynamic, the share dialog seems a better fit to just share the app than sharing a users score.

Is there a solution to this? Or do I need to make the Facebook open graph meta tags more dynamic to achieve the same result?

Comment: If you actually want to post game scores, then using the Scores API would be more appropriate. // It is correct that you can not set parameters (apart from the URL) dynamically using the Share dialog. If you want to do that, either make the post via API instead, or use parameterized URLs that deliver different meta information.

Comment: Well thats what I thought I needed to do, thanks for the comment! Well its not really scores, it was just an example. Could be anything other than the default OG tags.

Comment: You can use `/me/feed` with title, link, picture, caption & description, just note that pre-filling message field is not allowed by the policy

Comment: But to allow '/me/feed' API calls don't the user need to accept the 'publish_posts' permission? And therefore use the facebook login function? Would rather avoid that.